# Sum of an indeterminate limit: $\lim_{x\to0}\;\left(2x\sin\left(\frac{1}{2x^2}\right)-\frac{1}{x}\cos\left(\frac{1}{2x^2}\right)\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

> $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\;\left(2x\sin\left(\frac{1}{2x^2}\right)-\frac{1}{x}\cos\left(\frac{1}{2x^2}\right)\right)$

How do I solve this limit? If I evaluate, then the left part is something that goes to zero multiplied by something bounded, so zero. But the right part, I have seen it gives an indetermination (which I quite don't understand). I would appreciate an explanation or a hint of why that's the case, and how do I evaluate the sum of both. Thank you.

Comment: At first glance,  I can't see how that could possibly converge,  since you have bounded wild variations between -1 and 1 divided by something going to 0 in the second term.  I could definitely be wrong though

Comment: If the limit existed, approaching zero along two different sequences would give the same result. Take for instance $$
a_n  = \frac{1}{{2\sqrt {\pi n} }},\quad b_n  = \frac{1}{{\sqrt {(2n + 1)\pi } }}.
$$

Comment: From the looks of this: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/z037wpxedi The limit doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

Upon further thought,  yes, the limit doesn't exist.  The first part goes to 0, the second oscillates between $\pm \infty$,  so the whole thing oscillates

Comment: Do you think I would need any justification if I were on an exam for example? Because sometimes I think something it's too obvious and it's not, and viceversa. This does seem pretty straightforward.

Comment: I'd ask your instructor as that would vary per professor.  I'd take it, but another might want the rigorous proof of showing two sequences go to different values,  as per Gary's comment above